# How to set the min height of bar graph in angularjs charts?

Tags: angularjs, charts

Suppose if the values that we pass for the bar-graph are 10,100 and 500. Then the bar-graph thats plotted looks like below

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRIeE.png]

The code thats used is like

```
 $scope.options = {
                        scales: {
                            xAxes: [{
                                gridLines: {
                                    display: false
                                }
                            }],
                            yAxes: [{
                                gridLines: {
                                    display: false
                                },
                                ticks: {
                                    min: $scope.min,
                                    beginAtZero: true,
                                    //max: 3,
                                    //stepSize: 
                                },
                                display: true
                            }]
                        },
```

Please suggest me how to show the smaller value of bar-graph

Comment: What do you mean by "*the smaller value*" ...?

Comment: @davidkonrad : smaller value means the lowest value (number) which is almost near to base of graph. In above eg : Oct , whose value is 10 and so its bar is not seen at all.